# Route redirect to url but not render the view

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm learning Reactjs and Router, but my page is redirected to url but it's not contain any view.
[View before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnfjm.jpg)

This is my code :

```
import "./App.css";

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import HomePage from "./components/HomePage";
import QuestionPage from "./components/QuestionPage";
import firebase from "./util/firebase";

function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
  const todoRef = firebase.database().ref("NoteDatabase");
  useEffect(() => {
    const todoRef = firebase.database().ref("NoteDatabase");
    todoRef.on("value", (val) => {
      const dbList = val.val();
      const list = [];
      for (let id in dbList) {
        list.push(dbList[id]);
      }
      setArr(list);
    });
  }, []);

  const addTopic = (question, answer, path, label) => {
    if (question != null && answer != null) {
      todoRef.push({
        path: path,
        label: label,
        questions: [
          {
            header: question,
            answer: answer,
          },
        ],
      });
    } else {
      todoRef.push({
        path: path,
        label: label,
        questions: [
          {
            header: 'question',
            answer: 'answer',
          },
        ]
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <HomePage topics={arr} addTopic={addTopic} />
      </Route>

      {arr.map((item) => {
        console.log(item);
        return (
          <Route key={item.path} path={item.path} >
            <QuestionPage topic={item} addTopic={addTopic} />
          </Route>
        );
      })}
    </Switch>
  );
}

export default App;
```

questionpage:

```
import { Card } from "primereact/card";
import { Panel } from "primereact/panel";
import React from "react";
import ToolbarForQuestionPage from "./Toolbarjs";
export default function QuestionPage(props) {
  const addTopic = (question, answer, path, label) => {
    props.addTopic(question, answer, path, label);
  };
  const header = <ToolbarForQuestionPage label={props.topic.label} addTopic={addTopic}/>;
  const headerQues =(header)=> (<React.Fragment><p><i className="pi pi-question-circle p-px-2"></i> {header}</p></React.Fragment>);
  console.log('question page');
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      
      <Card header={header}>
        {props.topic.questions && props.topic.questions.map((item) => {
          return (

            <div className="p-col-12 p-m-3">
              <Panel header={headerQues(item.header)} toggleable collapsed='true'>
              
                <p>
                 {item.answer}
                </p>
              </Panel>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </Card>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

My Homepage route is loaded, but when I redirect to other route is just send to url but not contain any view.

#Update: my index.js:

```html
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

My Homepage:

```html
import "primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css";
import "primereact/resources/primereact.css";
import "primeicons/primeicons.css";
import "primeflex/primeflex.css";

import { Button } from "primereact/button";
import ButtonJs from "./ButtonJs";
import { Card } from "primereact/card";
import React from "react";
import Toolbarjs from "./Toolbarjs";

export default function HomePage(props) {
  const addTopic = (question, answer, path, label) => {
    props.addTopic(question, answer, path, label);
  };
  const header = <Toolbarjs isTopic={false} addTopic={addTopic} />;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="p-col-12 p-lg-6 p-md-12 p-m-auto">
        <Card header={header}>
          <div className="p-grid">
            {props.topics.map((item) => (
              <ButtonJs key={item.label} topic={item} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Here is where i use link (react-router-dom):

```html
import { Button } from "primereact/button";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";

export default function ButtonJs({ topic }) {
    const styleLink = {
        textDecoration:'none'
    }
  return (
    <div className="p-col-12 p-text-center ">
      <Link style={styleLink} to={topic.path}>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            console.log(topic);
          }}
          className="p-button-outlined p-col-12"
        >
          <i className="pi pi-book p-px-2"></i>
          <span className="p-px-3">{topic.label}</span>
        </Button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#Update more : firebase connect is ok , i can console.log it out

```html
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {label: "Hello1", path: "Hello1"}
1: {label: "Sin Hoc", path: "sin_hoc"}
2: {label: "asdsadas", path: "asdsadas"}
3:
  label: "njjjn"
  path: "njjjn"
  questions: Array(1)
  0: {answer: "answer", header: "question"}
  length: 1
  __proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

[Here is my HomePage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yLde.jpg) 
[But if i click one link in list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/738MB.jpg)

Comment: Can you update your question to include an example `arr` state array that is being rendered? Where are you rendering any `Redirect` component or imperatively redirecting? I see only `Switch` and `Route` components imported. Is there a `Router` wrapping your app somewhere near the root?

Comment: I am updated ^^

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with how you link to the routes, but it's still unclear what you're rendering for your routes, how paths are matched. Can you also add the `arr` state array value?

Comment: i uploaded it,thanks for helping , i really appreciate it

Comment: Ok, I see, the specified `path` properties are missing the leading `"/"` path prefix. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try wrapping the Switch with BrowserRouter?

Comment: yes, i updated it  ^^ i wrap it in index.js

Answer (score 0):

I forgot '/' in my path of router , thanks for helping :D